'import.meta' meta-property '--module' option error with vite and react in monorepo
error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.
const chatApiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_CHAT_API_URL || "";
Set up a jest testing configuration for an Nx monorepo react workspace. It uses vite.config.ts
The jest unit test cases written are failing with the import.meta issue.
This is the tsconfig.spec.json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
      "types": ["jest", "node"],
      "module": "esnext",
      "target": "esnext",
      "allowJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.spec.ts",
      "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
      "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }

This is the tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es2020"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vite/client", "jest", "node"],
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}


This is the tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {}
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "tmp"]
}


This is the jest.preset.ts
const nxPreset = require('@nx/jest/preset').default;
module.exports = {
    ...nxPreset,
    testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    resolver: '@nx/jest/plugins/resolver',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
    coverageReporters: ['html'],
};

This is the jest.config.ts
import { getJestProjects } from '@nx/jest';

export default {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
};

The VITE_CHAT_API_URL is defined in an .env.test file. The test case is written on a code where react is using signalR to communicate to the backend
const BACKEND_URI = "";
const chatApiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_CHAT_API_URL || "";
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(chatApiUrl, { withCredentials: false })
    .build();

connection.start()
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to SignalR hub"))
    .catch(err => console.error("Error connecting to SignalR hub: ", err));

This is spec file
import { getHeaders } from './api';

describe('getHeaders', () => {
    it('should return the Authorization header if useLogin is true, isUsingAppServicesLogin is false, and idToken is provided', async () => {
        const headers = await getHeaders('some-id-token');
        expect(headers).toEqual({ Authorization: 'Bearer some-id-token' });
    });
});


Tried multiple methods by updating the tsconfig files but the updates are not working out. Would like to get some help.

import.meta is specific to ES modules and Vite which isn't natively supported by Jest. Since Jest doesn’t directly support import.meta.env you can work around this issue by either mocking it within Jest or using a library like vite-jest or vite-plugin-env-compatible

Hi, Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it did not work for me :(
